# Python & SQL Server stored procedure hang

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I am trying to get Python to run a stored procedure in my SQL Server which kicks off a series of procedures which involves importing a file processing it and outputting a couple of files.

So far I have got my code so that it accepts an input to a table but then the whole thing hangs when it calls the stored procedure.

Checking `Who2` on the server it is waiting on the `preemptive_OS_Pipeops` which searching has revealed it is waiting on something outside of SQL Server to finish before proceeding.

Is someone able to shed some light if it is possible to use pyodbc to blind activate a stored procedure then close the connection?

My belief is by just telling the procedure to run then closing out should fix the issue but I am having issues finding the code for this

Python code:

```
    connection2 = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server}; Server=server;Database=db', timeout=1)
    cursor2 = connection2.cursor()
    cursor2.execute("{CALL uspGoBabyGo}")
    connection2.close()
    return 'file uploaded successfully'
```

Stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXECUTE [dbo].[uspCableMapImport]
END
```

Comment: If you close the connection the SP will stop running... it needs to run under a connection. You'll have to debug your SP and find out why its hanging.

Comment: As stated in the message the SP is hanging because of the Python call, I need the Python to just start the SP then close there is no further input required of the Python there is no output to Python by the SP, for security that is the way I have set it up so that all Python does is input a single value into a table then starts the SP.
The SP is hanging because of Python.

Comment: You can't close the connection or will stop the SP from completing.

Comment: "The SP is hanging because of the Python call" - what does this actually mean? How can the Python call affect the SP?

Comment: Stored procedure calls are synchronous - Python won't continue until the stored procedure completes or the (pyodbc?) statement times out. If you want the stored procedure to kick off an asynchronous process look into [Service Brokers and Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker) or some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and the script stopped posting the record to the table I found the solution to the issue. I needed to add in the autocommit=True line to the script, now the code is as follows;

```
    connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server}; 
    Server='Server';Database='DB';Trusted_Connection=yes')
    connection.autocommit=True
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    referee = file.filename.rsplit('.')[0]
    SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO RequestTable(Reference, Requested) VALUES ('"+ str(referee) +"', " + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ")")
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
    connection.commit
    SQLCommand2 = ("{CALL uspGoBabyGo}")
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand2)
    connection.commit
    connection.close()
```